# Is there alternatives (free or paid) for MPMoviePlayerController on the iphone?

Tags: iphone, video, video-streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller

Is there alternatives (free or paid) for MPMoviePlayerController on the iphone?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780999/mpmovieplayercontroller-alternatives-on-iphone

Answer (score 0):

You should give `UIMoviePLayerController` a try.